# How to map a URL with port number through Amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a web application on tomcat server in aws ec2 instance. I have also purchased domain from godaddy eg xyz.com.

Now I've done the mappings in AWS Route 53, and also updated the name servers of the domain.

Application is accessible with xyz.com:8080/ABCProject url but I need to access the same with xyz.com

Comment: DNS is all about mapping a Name to an IP address. The port number cannot be included in a DNS resolution.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use AWS ELB/ALB and create Listener on port 80/443 and backend with port 8000 and create alias record to point xyz.com to load balancer.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to expose the application on port 80. Or have some kind of reverse proxy (nginx for instance) / load balancer / api gateway sitting in front of the application that is available on port 80 and proxies calls to 8080. Whenever you go to any website without an explicit port number in the URL you are going via port 80.

Route53 is for managing DNS (name -> ip NOT name -> ip:port) it will not do what you want here.